# Implementation of date parameters in mdx query

Tags: reporting-services, ssas

In my cube i had debtdate dimension, now in ssrs i have implement that debtdate>=@startdate and debtdate<=@enddate parameters in dataset mdx main query...Can anyone please help me in this regard

Comment: What is your question? How to implement the parameter? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

You have not specified too much detail, but in general if you have two parameters @startDate and @endDate, which are both in string format like: "[Debt Date].[Calendar].[Date].&[datekey]", you can write something like:

```
SELECT
...
FROM (
    SELECT {StrToMember(@startDate):StrToMember(@endDate)} ON 0
    FROM [Your Cube]
)
```

in SSRS to get results for the range. If you want to say from @startDate to end of time you can give the @endDate parameter a Nothing (or NULL) value - and vice versa for beginning of time to @endDate.